# Put space after a specifc word in a string vector in R

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I want to put a space after a specific character in a string vector in R.

Example:

```
Text <-"<U+00A6>Word"
```

My goal is to put a space after the `">"` to seperate the string in two characters to come to: `<U+00A6> Word`

I tried with gsub, but I do not have the right idea:

```
Text = gsub("<*", " ", Text)
```

But that only puts a space after each character.

Can you advise on that?

Comment: You can edit your original question to fix the mistake.

Comment: What about `Text = gsub(">", "> ", Text)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sub(">", "> ", Text)
# [1] "<U+0093> Word"
```

or this (without repeating the `>`):

```
sub("(?<=>)", " ", Text, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "<U+0093> Word"
```

---

If you just want to extract `Word`, you can use:

```
sub(".*>", "", Text)
# [1] "Word"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to extract the word after the `>`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(Text, "(?<=>)\\w+")
#[1] "Word"
```

---

Or another option is `strsplit`

```
strsplit(Text, ">")[[1]][2]
#[1] "Word"
```